# how can i fix and optimize code for object detection on video

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, computer-vision, onnx

I wrote a code to recognize objects in a video. I trained yolov3 on my dataset and tested it with the detect.py script from this [repo](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3/blob/master/detect.py)
Network output:
[Network work example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjWK9.jpg)

I also checked the network on the video, everything works fine, also using the detect.py script.
The first problem I encountered was a lack of understanding of how to get a prediction from the network. I came across this [article](https://stackoverflow.com) and wrote this code:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn
import numpy as np
import torch

capture = cv2.VideoCapture("PATH")

CONFIDENCE = 0.5
SCORE_THRESHOLD = 0.5
IOU_THRESHOLD = 0.5

font_scale = 3
thickness = 5
boxes, confidences, class_ids = [], [], []

weights_path = "PATH"
net = dnn.readNetFromONNX(weights_path)
labels = ['hole']

#get video
while True:
    succces, img = capture.read()
    img = cv2.resize(img, (640,480))

    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255.0, (640, 640), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    ln = net.getLayerNames()[-1]
    layer_outputs = net.forward(ln)

    for output in layer_outputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > CONFIDENCE:
                box = detection[:4] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
                (centerX, centerY, width, height) = box.astype("int")
                x = int(centerX - (width / 2))
                y = int(centerY - (height / 2))
                boxes.append([x, y, int(width), int(height)])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    idxs = dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, SCORE_THRESHOLD, IOU_THRESHOLD)

    if len(idxs) > 0:
        for i in idxs.flatten():
            x, y = boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1]
            w, h = boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255,0,4), thickness=thickness)
            text = f"{labels[class_ids[i]]}: {confidences[i]:.2f}"
            cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                fontScale=font_scale, color=(0, 0, 0), thickness=thickness)

    cv2.imshow('Result', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

The first problem is that this code is very slow, about 1 frame per 5 seconds.
The second problem is that object detection does not work correctly, perhaps due to the conversion of the model to onnx format.
[onnx model output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yilQp.jpg)

I have an assumption that the code should be rewritten in c ++ and then it will be better, but there is one caveat. The code from the ultralitics repo is fast enough, but I don't understand it.

Comment: What kind of device are you using? Yolo is an  expensive algorithm.

Comment: @Micka I'm testing on the CPU, there is a geforce 1650 TI laptop graphics card, but it doesn't support CUDA, so I can't run on it. This code is written under jetson TX1, there is already support for CUDA: 256 cores.

Comment: what kind of CPU do you use? On an intel i7-8565U you can, afair, roughly expect about 1 fps for yolo v3 with 416x416 input size from the opencv call. So for 640x640 input it is about 1 frame per 2.5 seconds. If your cpu is slower the 1 frame per 5 seconds seems legit. For Jetson TX1 make sure opencv-dnn is compiled with opencv-dnn-cuda module (requirement: cuDNN, not sure whether this is even available for TX1), otherwise the CUDA cores wont be used for the DNN processing.

Comment: understood, thanks for the answer. why do you think the network can give an incorrect prediction?

Comment: not sure whether this is from your model, different preprocessing or something else. You should use identical images and a well known DNN to track down that problem by checking numerical identity of the DNN raw output in both processings.